# Portable UTF-8 Interface (Windows and Unix) without wide API

Tags: file-io, utf-8, portability, boost-locale

I am setting a path to a file on the harddrive using the following interface:

```
void setPath(const char* path);
```

This path will be used for basic file I/O.

If I for example provide a path containing Chinese characters ( e.g. via     QString::toUtf8()), this works fine for Unix, but of course doesn't for Windows because of the internal use of the wchar/wstring API.

I am now searching for an elegant way to make this interface UTF-8 compatible on both Windows and Unix based systems.
Is there a way to avoid the wide API on Windows based systems and keep using std::string and std::ofstream() ?

After looking at boost::locale this appears to me as a possibility to handle UTF-8 encoding. Would this be a way to go ( replacing the std::ofstream by its boost::ofstream() counterparts for example ? )

```
const std::locale loc = generator.generate(std::locale(), "zh_CN.UTF-8");
std::locale::global(loc);
std::cout.imbue(std::locale());
boost::filesystem::path::imbue(std::locale())
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to avoid the wide API on Windows based systems

The Windows API does not support UTF-8, except in a few select APIs.  Largely it only supports locale-dependent ANSI and UTF-16.  To support Unicode without losing data, you have to use the UTF-16 based APIs.

Your interface will need to internally convert UTF-8 strings to UTF-16 when passing them to Windows API functions, and convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 when receiving data from the API.  There is no other way.  This belongs in your underlying platform-specific logic, not in the higher-layer public interface.

> and keep using std::string and std::ofstream() ?

You can use `std::string` for UTF-8, and there are plenty of ways to convert between `std::string` UTF-8 and `std::wstring` UTF-16 (there are even classes in C++11 to handle that).

Microsoft has non-standard extensions to `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` in Visual Studio to accept UTF-16 filenames.  Other vendors may or may not provide similar functionality.